# How do I insert text above a table at the top of a Word document?

Tags: microsoft-word

This seems like it should be so basic, but it apparently isn't very intuitive.

**The scenario:** 
(1) I've inserted a table into a new blank MS-Word document. 
(2) I want to add some text outside and above the table.

**Problem:**
The table is butted right up against the top of the document and I can't move the cursor to a point before the table to insert any new text.

I've found that you can do this by cutting the table to the clipboard, type the new text and paste the table back, but there just has to be a more straightforward way to put the cursor at a point before a table that is at the top of a document.

Answer (score 81, accepted):

The active cursor is even with the *bottom left* of the table normally. You can just hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Home</kbd> to get to the very first character of the file, then <kbd>Enter</kbd> to move the table down.

If your table is positioned after the section break, or on top of any other page, or anywhere else for that matter, place the cursor in the *top left* cell of the table, and hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd> to insert a new line before the table.

Comment: Doesn't work, that puts the cursor in the top left cell of the table.

Comment: Correction, that DOES work, it just doesn't look like it. The cursor appears inside the fist/top cell, but hitting enter does indeed put the new-line outside of the table.

Comment: Glad to hear it helped!

Comment: Thank you
Ctrl+Shift+Enter  worked with me....20 years or more never though there is a fix for that :D and now just decided to Google it...

Comment: absolutely stunning! +1. I hope Microsoft would add a special marker for such locations when "flipped-P" is switched on

Comment: I was actually searching for how to "insert text above a" collapsible *heading* (not "table") "at the top of a Word document", but this thread was the closest thing I could find.  For a collapsible *heading*, Ctrl+Shift+Enter does insert a new page break in front, *but* when you start typing on that new page, you're still inside *another* collapsible *heading*.  To insert a new page break in front a collapsible *heading* "at the top of a Word document" *and* be outside of another collapsible *heading*, I tried and discovered that Ctrl+Enter will work.

Comment: On a ***Mac*** the keyboard shortcut is **Cmd+Shift+Enter**. https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/keyboard-shortcuts-in-word-95ef89dd-7142-4b50-afb2-f762f663ceb2?redirectsourcepath=%252fen-us%252farticle%252fkeyboard-shortcuts-in-word-for-mac-3256d48a-7967-475d-be81-a6e3e1284b25&ui=en-us&rs=en-us&ad=us#PickTab=macOS  Moth are keyboard shortcuts to insert a Column Break.

Answer (score 1):

If you've built a table that encompasses many pages and forgot to add a title on top of subsequent pages, which has happened to me quite a few times, I find that inserting a section break at the top left corner of your table (inside the first cell) gives you the space you need to copy and pace the title. Then you simply delete the section break (or not) and go about your life.

Answer (score 0):

Insert a new row to be a blank first row. Convert table to text. Done.

You need to ensure that your table vertical position is "Bottom" relative to margin otherwise new row keeps appearing on the previous page.