# Why can't I type text above a table?

Tags: microsoft-word, text-editing, text-formatting

Kindly see the screenshot beneath. This is the first page of the document:

[image: Page with table at the top]

After I followed user Mak's answer to change the table's *Text wrapping* to None:

[image: Table text wrapping: None]

Comment: The downward arrow always shows when your cursor is hovering above a table.Can you please provide more information on exactly what you're trying to do and what's happening? Is the row part of a table from the previous page?

Comment: Check your header row settings, you most likely have that set for a row on the previous page. Do you have a blank row on the previous page that is set to repeat header on every page (right click on the row, go to "Table Properties" and go to the "Row" tab and see if that box is checked)?

Comment: @MAK Thanks. Fixed. Can you pls remove your comment?

Comment: Please provide more information: what have you done, what do you want to do, what have you tried, what is happening, etc.? Are you showing the *first* page of the document or the ***only*** page? What happens when you click in the table, or to the left of it? Can you select rows? Can you delete rows? What happens if you delete row(s)? … … … … … … … … … … Please do not respond in comments; [edit] your question to make it clearer and more complete.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I insert text above a table at the top of a Word document?](https://superuser.com/questions/175177/how-do-i-insert-text-above-a-table-at-the-top-of-a-word-document)

Answer (score 1):

Verify in Table Properties the wrapping for the table.  It should be set to "None."

Comment: Thanks. Please see my edited post? 1. "your top margin is set well below the crop mark in the upper LH corner" - I decreased the Top Margin, but it didn't help. 2. "position your cursor in the top left cell and hit return" - didn't work. 3. "convert that row to text" - Still didn't work. After I converted row to text, the table row would disappear instantly.

Answer (score 1):

To insert text above a table that's on top of the page is very easy. Just move the cursor to the first position of the first cell with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Home</kbd> and then press <kbd>Enter</kbd>

Alternatively put your cursor on any cells in the first row of the table and press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd>

- [How Do I Type Text Above a Table at the Top of the Page?](https://www.knowledgewave.com/blog/msoffice/word/pc-tip-of-the-week-microsoft-office-word-2007-2.html)
- [How to insert a line above a table at the top of the document?](https://www.extendoffice.com/documents/word/1383-word-add-insert-line-before-above-table.html)
- [How do I insert text above a table at the top of a Word document?](https://superuser.com/q/175177/241386)
- [How do I type above a table in Microsoft Word?](https://www.quora.com/How-do-I-type-above-a-table-in-Microsoft-Word)
- [Insert a line above a Word table at the top of the page](https://www.techrepublic.com/blog/microsoft-office/insert-a-line-above-a-word-table-at-the-top-of-the-page/)

Comment: OP should've chosen one answer to make the question as answered. If I were them, I'd choose this

Answer (score 0):

If you are just trying to insert text before a table that's at the top of the page, that is easy. Put your cursor in the first row/column of the table, go to the Layout ribbon and select "Split Table".

Answer (score 0):

I also had the same problem, it was driving me nuts.
I found a simple solution:

Click on the Cross on the top left of the table or highlight the whole thing, copy it (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>) then delete it. Then write whatever at the start, then **BELOW** the text paste it (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd>). Then you can type anything on top and have the table below.